# Allowing space and enter key in android keyboard

Tags: android

I want to **InputFilter** in **EditText** to allow only alpha **(a-z or A-Z)** Space and Enter key.But I can only allow **(a-z and A-Z)**.

How to allow space and enter key?

This is my code :

```
protected InputFilter filterAlpha = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
        if(!source.equals("") && !ps.matcher(source).matches()){
            //Key not allowed
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};


EditText et_name_eng = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name_eng);
et_name_eng.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {filterAlpha});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your regex to "^[a-zA-Z \r\n]+$".